# A module which is not singular

Tags: modules, projective-module

Suppose that M is a projective R-module and that it's simple, isomorphic to $R/I$ where $I$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$ such that $I$ is not a direct summand of $R$. How to get to a contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a module $P$ is projective  then for a surjective module homomorphism $f : R \to P$ there exists a module homomorphism $h : P \to R$ such that $fh = {\rm id}$. So $P$ is a direct summand of $R$. More explicitly, $R = {\rm Im} (h) \oplus I$. The contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see why $R$ has that decomposition. I would say $R = {\rm Im} (h) \oplus R/I$. By the way, if M is module over R, is there a canonical epimorphism from R to M?

Comment: First, if $x\in {\rm Im} (h) \cap I$ then $x=h(y)$, so $0=f(x)= fh(y)=x$. Thus, ${\rm Im} (h) \cap I=0$. Second, for every $x\in R$ we have $f(x- hf(x))=0$, so $x- hf(x)\in I$. Hence $R= {\rm Im}+I$.